# What mathematical concepts do I need to master in order to understand the Aztec Procotol?

Tags: privacy, zero-knowledge

What mathematical concepts do I need to master in order to understand how privacy in the Aztec Protocol works?

When I look at the [white paper](https://github.com/AZTECProtocol/AZTEC/blob/master/AZTEC.pdf), I have no idea what is going on; however, I am confident in my ability to figure it out. The extent of my math knowledge is university level calculus.

Comment: From Mathematics Elliptic Curve Cryptography, Bilinear Pairing from Cryptography Zero Knowledge. Perhaps some Probability and Group Theory will be good also.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Ismael, the central ideas are elliptic curve cryptography and secure commit-reveal schemes.
The wikipedia page is a good start:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme

Good luck!